# My son is in jail and his hearing was vacated to a different date. Does he stay in jail?

Tags: criminal-law

My son is in jail. I went to court today and he wasn't on the docket
The clerks office told me his hearing was vacated till December 19. I'm not understanding whats going on. Does he remain in jail?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a jurisdiction. What happens in criminal proceedings varies depending on country and subdivision thereof.

Comment: It also depends on the charge: some offences are not bailable.

Comment: It also depends on the reason for the delay. If it's caused by the prosecutor, it may trigger limits that result in an automatic personal recognizance bond. ([Tex. Code Crim. Proc. art. 17.151](https://statutes.capitol.texas.gov/Docs/CR/htm/CR.17.htm#17.151))

Comment: As a practical matter, asking his public defender (assuming he has not hired a criminal defense attorney) would be the best option for getting an answer.